# How to gradually increase the width of a Canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable

I'm trying to implement a Waveform visualizer in my app which draws the waveform on a canvas from a real-time audio input. (Screenshot below)

What I need to do is to make it in a way that it can be scrolled horizontally from left to right.

I figured I should use a `HorizontalScrollView` and make the canvas gradually grow in width so that it spans over the screen width. Now I'm wondering how this can be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `Canvas`'s width the same and use the `canvas.translate()` method when actually drawing.

So, let's say you have a `Rect rect` that contains the rectangle to draw (whose boundaries may exceed that of the `View`), as well as `int horizontalOffset = 0` as the variable holding the offset of your drawing rectangle which will be adjusted as the user touches the `View`.

Now, when `onDraw(Canvas)` is called:

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save(); 
    canvas.translate(horizontalOffset, 0); 
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Then you can then override `onTouch(View, MotionEvent)` to calculate the horizontal offset based on the touch event and then `invalidate()` the `View`.

Note: this is clearly only drawing a `Rect`, but you should be able to modify what I did in there to draw whatever you're drawing. The important parts are (in order) `save()`, `translate()`, `draw`, `restore()`.